# ActiveRecord interfering with Logger

Tags: ruby, activerecord, logging, activesupport

It appears that using ActiveRecord (which requires ActiveSupport) messes with the Logger class, resulting in difficulties.  This can be seen with some example code:

```
require 'rubygems'
#require 'activerecord'
require 'logger'

log = Logger.new(STDERR)
log.sev_threshold = Logger::INFO
log.datetime_format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"

log.debug "debug"
log.info "info"
log.warn "warn"
log.error "error"
log.fatal "fatal"
```

Running this code will produce this lovely output:

```
I, [2009-09-02 10:49:39#27562]  INFO -- : info
W, [2009-09-02 10:49:39#27562]  WARN -- : warn
E, [2009-09-02 10:49:39#27562] ERROR -- : error
F, [2009-09-02 10:49:39#27562] FATAL -- : fatal
```

However, if I uncomment the require 'activerecord' line, I instead get this:

```
info
warn
error
fatal
```

So I did some searching about and after looking at activesupport:

[logger.rb](http://github.com/rails/rails/blob/669fd84910586d4c791b6f5bf4320f68ac7845aa/activesupport/lib/active_support/core_ext/logger.rb)

I found the following "working solution"

```
log = Logger.new(STDERR)
log.sev_threshold = Logger::INFO
log.datetime_format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"
class Formatter
      Format = "%s, [%s#%d] %5s -- %s: %s\n"

      attr_accessor :datetime_format

      def initialize
        @datetime_format = nil
      end

      def call(severity, time, progname, msg)
        Format % [severity[0..0], format_datetime(time), $$, severity, progname, msg2str(msg)]
      end

      private
        def format_datetime(time)
          if @datetime_format.nil?
             time.strftime("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.") << "%06d " % time.usec
          else
            time.strftime(@datetime_format)
          end
        end

        def msg2str(msg)
          case msg
          when ::String
            msg
          when ::Exception
            "#{ msg.message } (#{ msg.class })\n" <<
            (msg.backtrace || []).join("\n")
          else
            msg.inspect
          end
        end
end
f=Formatter.new
f.datetime_format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"
log.formatter=f
```

Using the above, I get the output that I like.  However, that seems to me gross and unRubylike.  Does anyone know if there is an easier way to get the desired result?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

The same Problem bugged me the last Hour, but the Solution is quite simple.

ActiveSupport uses the SimpleFormatter, you have to set the 'old' Formatter by hand.

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'active_support'
require 'logger'

log = Logger.new(STDERR)
log.sev_threshold = Logger::INFO
log.datetime_format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"
log.formatter = Logger::Formatter.new
```

Ps: Sry for my bad English :)